# how can i scroll to #target - 100px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use

```
<a href="#target">Details</a>

<div id="target">asd...</div>
```

but I also have top popup menu. So it's getting behind that menu.

Is it possible to write a JavaScript (also I'm already using bootstrap and jquery libraries on my template) go to `#target - 100px`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Never tried, but something like this should work.

```
 $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top - 100
 }, 1000); // this is the time in millisecond of the animation
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple JavaScript only solution is:

```
window.scrollTo(x,y)
```

For your example you would use:

```
window.scrollTo(0,100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Include Ariel Flesler's jquery.scrollTo-min.js

http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js

Step2: Add

```
$('a').scrollTo( $('#target'), 1000, {offset:-100} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top)-300
```

This is my code and it's works. -300 = pixels